# No shipping or Payment showing in Admin for new users

Tags: orders, customer, sales-order, admin-panel

When creating an order in Admin we are experiencing the issue where there is no option for shipping or payments. This seems to happen only when creating a new user.

There is no other consistent pattern.

(2) websites
(5) customer groups

Default customer is assigned to default store and the consumer group.

Answer (score 0):

For shipping option : you have to select product and add to cart than it will show you the shipping methods.
For Payment option : set which payment method you need from system > configuration > payment methods.